# ReactJS: Typescript .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

**ReactJS** Newbie question

In this typescript example, I get the error that `this.state.map` is not a function, but the props is set to an array??

```
class App extends React.Component<IProfile[],any>  {

constructor(props:IProfile[]) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { profiles: props };
    console.log(this.state);
}

public render() {

    return (<div>
                {this.state.profiles.map((profile: IProfile) => <Card {...profile} />)}
            </div>);
}
```

};

I call it with this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <App {...testData}/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

where:

```
const testData = [
{ name: "Dan Abramov", avatar_url: 
    "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", company: "@facebook" },

   ];
```

Comment: Can you post the code where `<App>` is created? So we can see how the props is being set.

Comment: Can props be an array object? I'm surprised you're not getting a compiler warning on line 1.

Comment: I've updated the post with some more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.state` is an object of which you assign fields to.  Your constructor should look more like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        profiles: props.profiles
    };
}
```

and then you can map like this:

```
return (
    <div style={{ background: 'green', width: 50 }}>
        {this.state.profiles.map((profile: IProfile) => <Card {...profile} />)}
    </div>
);
```

When passing data into your component you have a couple options:

#### Passing a named variable

This can be used when you only want to pass a few props from the parent component to the child component.

In your example, if you want to pass `testData` down into the App component to appear as `profiles` in App component's props, you would do this:

```
const testData = [
    { name: "Dan Abramov", 
    avatar_url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", 
    company: "@facebook" 
  },
];

ReactDOM.render(
   <App profiles={testData}/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This will provide `testData` as `this.props.profiles` in the App component.

#### Passing multiple fields at once

Say you have multiple fields you want to pass, stored in an object like so:

```
testData = {
    profiles: [...],
    createdAt: ...,
    isValid: true
}
```

You can pass all this data at once using this syntax:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <App {...testData}/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This will provide access to all the fields in the child component with the names they have in the original object like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    /* This will print:
        { profiles: [...], isValid: true, createdAt: ... }
    */
}
```

You can also combine both of them to pass some named data, as well as the rest as props.  This is common in [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o87rwp2L/) for you to look at.

Comment: I agree. I think this is the better way to do it instead of trying to set the state as an array.

Comment: I've updated the post to use the change in state you suggested, strangely I get the same error, this times it says that    TypeError: this.state.profiles.map is not a function no. When I remove that line and just dump this.state.profiles to the console, I see an array. Is this.state.profiles not initialized when it's called perhaps? I console.log the constructor out to check I get good data

Comment: When passing the data as props using the shorthand you've tried ( {...testData} ), you should be passing an object.  Using the spread operator turned the testData into an object, which consequently has no map function.  
I'll update my answer for you.